# Make a list of all words in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'c1':'Hello world'}, {'c1':'Hello all the world'}])
```

I want to make a list with all the the words contained in the column "c1". The resulting list should look like this:

```
list=['Hello','world','Hello','all','the','world']
```

I thought I could iterate over the rows in the dataframe and for each row loop through the words in "c1" and output the words to a list, but I can't make it work.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 7):

You can do like this:

```
' '.join([i for i in df['c1']]).split()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
df.stack().str.split("[^\w+]").explode().tolist()
```

Outputs:

```py
['Hello', 'world', 'Hello', 'all', 'the', 'world']
```

Answer (score 2):

First we create the sample `df` and empty list `a_list`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'c1':'Hello world'}, 
                   {'c1':'Hello all the world'}]) 
a_list = []
```

```
for value in df.c1.str.split(' '):
    a_list.extend(value)
```

This [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) iterates through each row in column `c1`, does work on the value in each row, then adds the output to `a_list` via `.extend` function.

What's happening from left to right, bot to top:
`for`  : starts the loop.
`value`: is a temporary variable used to store the value within each row of `c1` column.

`df.c1` : selects `c1` column from `df`
`.str.split()` : accesses the the string value and splits where there are spaces(`' '`), turning those row values into lists

`a_list.extend(value)` :
adds `value` with each iteration to `a_list`

Print the list

```
print(a_list) 
['Hello', 'world', 'Hello', 'all', 'the', 'world']
```

Comment: Only the second answer works.

First answer gives: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'
Third answer: ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.

Regarding second answer which works, can you explain what is happening?